# ArcGIS Server 10 JavaScript API offline

Tags: arcgis-server, arcgis-maps-sdk-javascript

Is there any way to have all the required files of JavaScript API? Because I have a local application and the user won't be able to have the resources from serverapi.arcgisonline.com

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can download and install the API from this location: http://www.esri.com/apps/products/download/index.cfm?fuseaction=download.all#ArcGIS_API_for_JavaScript